# $W$ Boson scattering off another $W$ (Feynman diagrams)

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

I am somewhat confused on how to solve this. The statement "at most one virtual particle" is the one that is puzzling me. Any advice on how to think about this?

[image]

Comment: In the context of he diagrams above, the incoming and outgoing Ws are considered real particles, i.e. on mass shell.

Comment: The rule of thumb is that in normal Feynman diagrams the internal lines are virtual and external lines are real.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many diagrams you can draw, but they will have 2 or more virtual particles: there are 3 diagrams you can draw with 0 or 1 (i.e at most 1) virtual particles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that we can draw infinite diagrams, my question was how to get to the 3 other diagrams(in addition to the 2 shown) that have at most 1 virtual particle. Did you mean to say that only possible diagrams with at most 1 virtual particle are the ones shown?

Comment: @Abhi There are in total 7 tree-level diagrams that contribute. You have three drawn in your post (I count them as three since the "first" one can be with either a photon or a Z boson in the middle) and you are missing 4 more. Three of them are similar to the ones you have and one is completely different.

Comment: @FrodCube Thanks for the hint. Are 3 of the ones got by interchanging W+ and W- on the right hand vertex and the 4th one a 4 boson vertex? In that case, I am slightly confused what stops us from interchanging the W+ and W- in the 4 boson vertex too and call it another diagram?

Comment: @Abhi the initial and final state must stay the same, so you shouldn't exchange external legs. Google for the difference between s-channel, t-channel and u-channel diagrams and you should understand. And yes, the 4th diagram is the 4 boson vertex.

Comment: @FrodCube Thanks for the hint. The ones I have drawn are t channel, there are 3 more u channel(one for each t) and the 4th is a 4 vertex one. Therefore there are 7 in total. Just leaving it here for people who stumble across similar question in future.